# Drools accessing generated java files

Tags: java, drools

I am executing Drools rule through Mockito test. The rule fails at run time reporting the error with a line number of a java file having some long arbitrary name. It seems that Drools generates java files on the fly and injects into JVM. But when I search those files on my disc I don't find any. Is there a way I could store them on my disc?

Comment: What is the error you're getting? If it is compiling files it's likely storing them in a temporary location and cleaning them up on completion - so you'd never find them. However the error should point to the actual class file somewhere in it's output.

Comment: This should be a rule compile error, not a runtime (rule execution time) error. Compile the DRL file outside of Mockito, and you should see an error message when you ask the builder for the accumulated errors.

Comment: I get NullPointerException this doesn't look by any mean a rule compile error.

Answer (score 11):

Got the solution:

You can dump the Drools generated java files in two ways.

1) Through command line:

```
-Ddrools.dump.dir="target/dumpDir"
```

e.g. I use maven command to execute the rule so it would be

```
mvn -Ddrools.dump.dir="target/dumpDir" -Dtest=DroolsRuleTest test
```

2) Through the API

```
public class FileKnowledgeBaseFactory implements KnowledgeBaseFactory {
    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(FileKnowledgeBaseFactory.class);

    public KnowledgeBase load(String drlFullFilename) {
        KnowledgeBuilderConfiguration config = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilderConfiguration();
        config.setOption(DumpDirOption.get(new File("target/dumpDir")));

        KnowledgeBuilder knowledgeBuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder(config);

        ....
        ....
    }
}
```