# Drools error: Error evaluating constraint 'String' in [Rule "Cold check" in drules.drl]]

Tags: java, drools

I'm trying to write a simple rule that finds the probability of a patient having the cold based on symptoms provided. It checks all possible symptoms of the cold by increasing the initial 0 by 1 each time one of the provided symptoms matches the one found in cold. In the end, the total value is divided by the total number of possible cold symptoms. This is first time i'm writing a rule by the way, so i would also take any suggestions if you think i should make the rule differently.

```
rule "Cold check"
    when
        $p: DoctorsAppointment() and //doctor's appointment which contains symptoms (symptoms are modelled as enumeration) that patient has
        $b: HashMap(String, Double) //hashmap which contains all diseases in the form key="disease name", value=0.0 initially.
    then
        for(Symptom s : $p.getSymptoms()) {
            if(s==Symptom.RUNNING_NOSE) {
                $b.put("cold", ((Double) $b.get("cold")) + 1.0);
            }
            else if(s==Symptom.SORE_THROAT) {
                $b.put("cold", ((Double) $b.get("cold")) + 1.0);
            }
            else if(s==Symptom.HEADACHE) {
                $b.put("cold", ((Double) $b.get("cold")) + 1.0);
            }
            else if(s==Symptom.SNEEZING) {
                $b.put("cold", ((Double) $b.get("cold")) + 1.0);
            }
            else if(s==Symptom.COUGHING) {
                $b.put("cold", ((Double) $b.get("cold")) + 1.0);
            }
        }
        $b.put("cold", ((Double) $b.get("cold"))/6);
end
```

I receive the following error:

```
[dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Error evaluating constraint 'String' in [Rule "Cold check" in drules.drl]] with root cause

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
```

Comment: Have you tried using just `HashMap()` or `Map()` instead of `HashMap(String, Double)` in the conditional?

Comment: You could also try checking the Java source file it generates for the rule. For that, you can refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/21762399/738746.

Comment: What you have in your rule is not valid Drools' syntax. Please read the user manual and correct your `HashMap` pattern.

Comment: Yes, the HashMap syntax was wrong. Thank you both for your help.