# How to convert strings into int in drools decision table

Tags: drools

I'm having a hard time converting a string into int so I can perform math operations on it. I tried to use the `parseInt` method in a `.drl` file but somehow it doesn't work in a decision table.

So far this is what I have:

[image]

And this is the error I'm getting when I'm trying to use it:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while creating KieBase[Message [id=1, kieBase=dtables, level=ERROR, path=D:\Users\cabanuz\eclipse-workspace\demo_drools\target\classes\com\sample\dtables\Payment_Hierarchy.xlsx, line=5, column=0
   text=Rule Compilation error Syntax error on token ".", delete this token]]
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.getKieBase(KieContainerImpl.java:378)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.getKieBaseFromKieSessionModel(KieContainerImpl.java:560)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.newKieSession(KieContainerImpl.java:536)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.newKieSession(KieContainerImpl.java:506)
    at com.manulife.payment_hierarchy.main.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:14)
```

I get my data from a hash map. That is why all of the values are string. Any idea on how to do this will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you put Integer into your map?

Comment: Unfortunately, due to a design we decided, it has to remain as a string

Answer (score 0):

It appeared to work with no explicit conversion for me, just

```
int i = '5';
$object.setInt(i);
```

the only issue I face with your code is that you are writing 'then block code' in C7, but it should be placed in C8, and this generates totally insane drl for me. Do you have [generated DRL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21762399/drools-accessing-generated-java-files/21775905)?

Comment: thanks for pointing out that my `then block code` is supposed to be in C8 instead of C7. I tried your code but I ended up getting a type mismatch error. After trying my code and placing it in C8, it finally worked. Can't believe it was that simple. Thanks a lot

Comment: Yeah. It was triggered when I tried to assign it into the int variable. Anyway, moving it to C8 fixed the problem.

Comment: are you still trying to use parseInt(toString(...))?

Comment: yeah I still do